# Need rewrite for URL with specific string

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I need help with one redirect, unfortunately I don't have idea how to write this for Wordpress. Should be .htaccess redirect or function in functions.php? Noob I am, so please help :)

OK, I have post, for example `mysite.com/post1/`
now, i have plugin that adding image to post as `mysite.com/post1/thumb_image1.jpg` but for some reason this plugin also adding page `mysite.com/post1/mysite.com/post1/image1.jpgTHUMB` that does not exist, so giving me 404 I need to sort. Now I can not remove this plugin, but how can I say to google not to crawl link `mysite.com/post1/mysite.com/post1thumb_image1.jpgTHUMB`
and if it does (or someone accidentally find it) than do 301 on that link and redirect it to parent post, so example `mysite.com/post1/`

so something like Redirect 301 `mysite.com/ABC/**.jpgTHUMB` to `mysite/com?ABC` There are a lot of posts so this should apply to any post in my website.
I think that above is possible through some kind of redirect, but I read like 60 pages and tried so many options and nothing works. now got headache of all this code, so please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should solve this at the plugin level. While this rewrite rule …

```
RewriteRule (.*)/?mysite.com/(.*) /$1/$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)THUMB /$1 [L,R=301]
```

… does what you are asking for, it is just cosmetic. Find the code that creates the wrong URL and fix that. Give the plugin author feedback; I’m sure s/he wants to know about that issue.

Comment: Hi toscho, thank you for comment and help. yes, i need just a quick fix before i find a way to modify plugin. Your example didn't work for me :( is there a rewrite that will return any URL containing /THUMB to parent post? So if I have mysite.com/post57/THUMB45/875/this.jpg it will redirect it to mysite.com/post57/

Comment: @Dean See my update.

Comment: Hi toscho, thank a lot - that worked perfectly! Thank you for UPDATE your code is brilliant. But when checking links I discover another issue  - this time links start with "?link=" instead of "THUMB" - can i use code like:
RewriteRule (.*)/?mysite.com/(.*) /$1/$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?link= /$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: Please edit your question: Add a link to the plugin, so we can look at its source code.

Comment: Hi toscho, thank you a lot for your offers, but this plugin is paid so i can not share or distribute code. and there is no response from author. i'll have to patch this few issues for now :( thank for your help :)

Comment: toscho, is there a way i can email you? or send you pm?

Comment: I don’t give private support. :) You could ask a new question to find another way to get what your current plugin does. Just better.

Comment: OK, thanks toscho. i have other developers available, just sound like your are very good with wp. i'll visit Germany for Oktoberfest this year, so taste good food & beer over there :)